# What is the JSON syntax to format > center-align text in a SharePoint column

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I've used the below piece of code to hightlight a date in the past (column name is 'Due Date') in a SharePoint Online list. It works OK (color is red for past dates, and green for the rest). 
The text, however is not centered (nor horizontally, nor vertically) even though I've included this:   "text-align": "center",   "vertical-align": "center", which I've highlighted in bold in the piece of code below.

What is it that I am missing? Many thanks in advance.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": "true",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
  **"text-align": "center",
  "vertical-align": "center",**
  "background-color": "=if([$Due_x0020_Date] <= @now, '#ffcccc', '#ccffcc'"  

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise of vertical-align is that the element is an inline horizontal element or a table-cell element, including span, img, input, button, td, and the element whose display level is inline level or table-cell is changed by display. This also means that by default, div, p and other elements set the vertical-align invalid.

Text-align is also valid for inline-block elements. You can convert it to an inline/inline-block element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I did not manage to solve it replacing div with span or other inline elements (same results, and probably I need more experience with these elements), but your help allowed me to explore other possibilities and I found one with a div child and adding some width and margin: auto

Comment: Very happy to help you! If you have any questions in the future, you can ask me, I will do my best to help.